# Will I need a passport to fly domestic in September 2019? I have an Illinois state ID

Tags: usa, paperwork, domestic-travel

I am flying to Savannah, Georgia on Sept. 20, 2019 from Chicago. I have an Illinois state ID. Will a passport be required?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Illinois state web page](https://realid.ilsos.gov/) on the subject, you are OK until October 1st. 2021. After that, you will either need a "Real ID" issued by the state, or some other document such as a passport.

Comment: Why Is the Illinois State id not a "real Id" ....????

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ The US tries very hard to pretend not to have a national identity card. However, the Federal Government has stated rules for the issuing of state driver's licenses and ID cards. If a state ID does not follow those federal rules it will not be considered a "Real Id" for some federal purposes, including the TSA identity checks for air travel.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ It is a "real ID," just not a "Real ID," sometimes rendered "[REAL ID](https://www.dhs.gov/real-id)" in an attempt to avoid exactly this confusion.